# Retrieving the navigation history for the current running application

Tags: android, android-activity

I want a way to show the user where he is currently in the App. Example, if I have `activity A`,`activity B`, `activity C` and so on...If he navigates to `activity E` (for ex)..He should be able to see the history of how he has landed up on the current screen--(From Home->E or from home->a->b and then e or likewise. The history to be precise..)..I have read abt the activity stack on developer forums but have still not got a way to hook up into the stack trace of the activity...Help please..

Comment: you have try to use getStackTrace() for getting stack trace  of app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getStackTrace()` for getting  navigates infromation:

```
  StackTraceElement traceElement = Thread.currentThread()  
  .getStackTrace()[3];
  String logText = String.format(CLASS_METHOD_LINE_FORMAT,  
  traceElement.getClassName(), traceElement.getMethodName(),  
  traceElement.getLineNumber(), traceElement.getFileName());  
  Log.d("messg", logText);
```

or

cat /data/anr/traces.txt

but You need to have root access to modify the files in `/data/`

Comment: @KunalShah : what not working edit your post with code this is stacktarce for your appliction.it will give all info for your app

Comment: Imran, first I copied and pasted ur code...but the constant CLASS_METHOD_LINE_FORMAT gave an error and was not compiling in eclipse...then what I did was remove that and gave a "" in that parameter...after that I did run the proj again and it logged nothing :(

Comment: the app demands that the user knows where he is in the app, so commenting in the release mode wont be of all that help..anyway would try the code and get back to u...\